# Can't insert data to mysql database with awk

Tags: mysql, linux, awk

I'm trying to insert some data fom a .tsv file to a mysql database using awk. When I run this, I just get the mysql rules back at the command line. Any ideas?

Here's the command I am using:

`awk '{print "INSERT INTO scores(id, score) VALUES('\''"$1"'\'', "$2");"}' "data.tsv" | mysql -u "user" -p "passw" db`

I'm not getting any error messages back, but I check my database and no rows have been inserted.

Comment: don't you need a "go" command to trigger an action in `mysql` (you do with the DBs I'm used to using). Good luck.

Comment: Maybe try `mysql -u user -ppassw --database=db`

Comment: @spencer7593 I understand that my question wasn't well-formed, and I will keep this feedback for future questions. My question basically was "what's wrong with this piece of code, it's intended to insert data in my database but its not doing that and I'm basically getting no errors back". However, I do not understand why was this rude tone necessary. I didn't force anyone to help me. This is a questions forum, and people sometimes ask rookie questions. I did my fair share of online searching and couldn't find anything, so I came here. Nothing wrong with that. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to remove the space between `-p "passw"`, like this:

```
    | mysql -u "user" -p"passw" db
```

Comment: Ah, I knew this would be something really simple. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The other answer already hinted that the `-p` flag has special, counter-intuitive behavior in the mysql client. If you have a space after it, it makes the mysql client prompt you for a password. The argument following is NOT taken as the password, it's taken as the next argument unrelated to `-p`.

The following two commands are equivalent:

```
mysql -u <user> -p <databasename>

mysql -p -u <user> <databasename>
```

If you want to include the password, you must have *no space* after the `-p`:

```
mysql -u <user> -p<password> <databasename>
```

To make scripts more clear, I like to use the long option names:

```
mysql --user=<user> --password=<password> <databasename>
```

But you shouldn't be using passwords on the command-line anyway, because then anyone who can run `ps` can see your password. Instead, put user & password into an [options file](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) and have the client read it.

```
mysql --defaults-file my.cnf <databasename>
```

Your awk code is going to output a long series of SQL injection vulnerabilities. I mean, you're trusting that all the content in your .tsv file is safe to insert, won't contain any characters like apostrophes that will do anything unexpected to the SQL syntax. For example, what happens if `$1` is "O'Hare"?

Awk doesn't have any function to do string-escapes to protect you from this, nor any feature to do **parameterized queries**, which is a better method of running safe SQL statements with dynamic values.

I have used awk for other tasks for many years, but I wouldn't use it for this task. For example, in Ruby:

```
require 'mysql2'
require 'csv'

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :database => "test", :username => "...")

sql = client.prepare("INSERT INTO scores (id, score) VALUES (?, ?)")

CSV.open('data.tsv', col_sep: "\t", liberal_parsing: true) do |csv|
  csv.each do |row|
    sql.execute(*row)
  end
end
```

Another alternative to load TSV files, with much better performance, is to use [mysqlimport --local](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html). But there are some [configuration values you need to set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data-local.html) to get this to work on a default MySQL instance, and the filename must have the same name as the table (except for the .tsv file extension).

Example: I loaded a .tsv file with four lines of text into a table `test.scores`:

```
mysqlimport --local test scores.tsv
test.scores: Records: 4  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: +10. important points about sql injection vulnerabilities, about using the long form for parameters, avoiding password on command line with `--extra-defaults-file=` option. Personally, I'd use `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement, which is what mysqlimport is doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Yeah, you're right that mysqlimport is just a CLI to the LOAD DATA INFILE statement. I almost linked to the LOAD DATA INFILE doc, but since the user is using awk I thought it would be easier to show the command-line tool one can run at a shell prompt without needing to use the mysql client.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks a lot for the detailed and informative answer! I appreciate it and it was very educational, I will definitely keep all of this in mind!